# OWIN Signin not working

Tags: owin, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, claims, owin-middleware

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false. I've been googling for hours and I cannot get this to work. I have a set of claims and I'm creating the identity and signing in with it using OWIN, but for some reason, IsAuthenticated is always false.

Here is my web.config relevant portion:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="FormsAuth1" loginUrl="https://localhost/SecureAuth.ClaimsAdapter.WebApp/Oidc/Authenticate" timeout="5" requireSSL="false"  domain="localhost"  />
</authentication>
```

Here is Startup.Auth.cs

```
 app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/OIDC/Authenticate")
 });
```

Here is my controller

```
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(validatedToken.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        //Sign in using the created identity
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

        //redirect to Pass the cookie to the client app
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
```

In the "Confirm" action, the "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is still set to false.

Comment: Forms authentication and the OWIN authentication middleware are separate concepts. Calling `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn()` won't do anything to forms auth.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'm still getting the hang of things owin

Comment: But shouldn't GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn set the User Authentication to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I wasn't calling the

ConfigureAuth(IappBuilder app) ....

Proceed to slap self...

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.AuthenticationType` to the same type as your `DefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType`.

This should work

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        //Change this to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/OIDC/Authenticate")
    });


//Change this to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(validatedToken.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

//Sign in using the created identity
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

//redirect to Pass the cookie to the client app
return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
```

Comment: Thanks, Kahbazi, but that didn't work either. I did exactly as your mentioned....